# Angularjs Open Window With Post Params

Tags: angularjs

I have a two forms in my application.

In the first one the user sets his data. When submitted the form data gets checked and an entry is made into a database with $http.

The second one is hidden and contains the payment parameters for either paypal or amazon payments.

I need one of two solutions (I can do A but my gut feeling is that B is better):

A) 
Trigger the submit function of form B when the promise of form A's http is resolved.

This would be one solution which is not very good I guess:

**HTML**

```
      <form method="POST" action="{{spendenController.paypal.actionUrl}}" target="_top" id="paypalForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{spendenController.paypal.accountEmail}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{spendenController.spenden.amount}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Spende">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{spendenController.paypal.notifyUrl}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{spendenController.paypal.successRedirectUrl}}" />
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="btnSubmit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal.">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      </form>
```

**Controller**

```
document.getElementById('paypalForm').submit()
```

B)
Or load a page with POST params directly from the controller/a service when the promise is resolved. In that case I wouldn't even need the second form.

**Question:** How to open a page with POST from the controller?

I do not just want to send POST data with $http.post I need the user to see the paypal checkout window in order to fulfill the payment.

Comment: You can use `ng-submit` on the `form` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: I thought about this solution but if I integrate multiple payment providers I have to exchange that. Best would be to have it all in a service.